# How to rearrange $py'' + (2l+2-2p)y' + 2(n-l-1)y = 0$ into $2py'' + (2l+2-2p)y' + (n-l-1)y = 0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, quantum-mechanics, laguerre-polynomials

I have a 2nd order homogenous ODE:
$$py'' + (2l+2-2p)y' + 2(n-l-1)y = 0$$
where y is a function of p and n and l are variables

Its solution is the associated Laguerre polynomials $L_{n-l-1}^{2l+1}(2p)$
I have expanded out the solution to try and 'meet in the middle' to get this:
$$2py'' + (2l+2-2p)y' + (n-l-1)y = 0$$
But I just can't work out how to rearrange the first one to achieve the second.

If anyone would like to know where this equation comes from, it is the 'main' part of the radial equation for the hydrogen atom (i.e. it is the radial equation with the asymptotic solutions removed). In most textbooks it is denoted $v(\rho)$.

Edit: Thanks to Robert Israel's helpful answer I'm aware that the second differential equation above does not have the solution of the Laguerre polynomials $L_{n-l-1}^{2l+1}(2p)$. If anyone could tell me the correct differential equation that does have those solutions I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two equations are not the same, but they are related.  Using Maple I get $L^{2l+1}_{n-2}(2p)$ as a solution of the first, but $L^{n/2-1/2-l/2}_{l}(p)$ as a solution of the second. [Caution: conventions may difer]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've repeated my process several times but the differential equation I get never has the right laguerre polynomials as the solution (I checked using wolfram alpha after you pointed out the mistake and that concurred with maple). Would you mind showing me what the differential equation would be for the Laguerre polynomials $L_{n-l-1}^{2l+1}(2p)$?

Comment: It looks to me like that satisfies the differential equation
$$ p y'' + (2 l - 2 p + 2) y' + (2 l + 2 n - 2) y = 0$$

Comment: Thanks, nice to see this is my starting equation. Would you mind telling me how you worked that out or point me to some resource that would help me? I'm very confused about how to find get to the differential equation from the solution and vice versa

Comment: Assuming a differential equation of the form $p y'' + (a + bp) y' + c y = 0$, take the desired $y$ and its first and second derivatives (noting the identity $L_{n}^{\left(a \right)}\! \left(x \right) = 
\frac{\left(2 n +a -1-x \right) L_{n -1}^{\left(a \right)}\! \left(x \right)}{n}-\frac{\left(n +a -1\right) L_{n -2}^{\left(a \right)}\! \left(x \right)}{n}
$), and see what $a, b, c$ have to be to make this true.